# The ratio of masses in an elastic collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

> Two blocks of mass $M_1$ and $M_2$ moving along a 1-dimensional straight line with velocities $V_1$ and $V_2$, respectively, collide elastically. After the collision they move with respective velocities $U_1$ and $U_2$. What is the ratio $M_1/M_2$ if the velocities are to be interchanged, ie, $U_1=V_2$ and $U_2=V_1$?

I'm very confused as to where to begin in regards to this question. I've tried rearranging the conversation of momentum equation ($m_1v_1 + m_2v_2 = m_1u_1 + m_2u_2$) to express it in terms of $m_1$ and $m_2$ and then dividing them into each other. However this leaves me with $m_1$ and $m_2$ on both sides which is definitely incorrect. Is there an easier way to find the ratio?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You can use very simple algebra to get $m_1$ on one side and $m_2$ on the other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considering momentum:
$$m_1u_1+m_2u_2=m_1v_1+m_2v_2$$
Therefore,
$$m_1u_1-m_1v_1=m_2v_2-m_2u_2$$
Factorising gives us:
$$m_1(u_1-v_1)=m_2(v_2-u_2)$$
Allowing us to rearrange to:
$$\frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}}=\frac{v_{2}-u_{2}}{u_{1}-v_{1}}$$
Using the fact that you say the velocities can be interchanged, we obtain a final answer of:
$$\frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}}=\frac{v_{2}-v_{1}}{v_{2}-v_{1}}$$
This final step gives a ratio of 1 between the two masses.

Comment: The correct ratio is one.  Think about what happens when one billiard ball hits another completely head-on without any spin effects.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Of course - I was overlooking the fact that the velocities are interchanged, so was confused by the apparent value of 1. This makes sense now, I will edit the answer!

Comment: Its a bit confusing how this can be correct math since you have Kg = ms^-1 as an equation. Its a bit quirky.